# Excel-Is is able to return current result if the condition fails

Tags: excel

Below table describes what I expect for.

The "Count Blank" Column is a counter for counting **continuous** blank cells in order from Column A to Column C. If any of the following cell has value then stop counting and return current value. (plz see row6 and row7)

Basically, I'm looking for a formula which could return the current counter value if the condition fails.

| Count Blank | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 |  | 2 | 3 |
| 2 |  |  | 3 |
| 3 |  |  |  |
| 1 |  | 2 |  |
| 0 | 1 |  |  |

These two formulas are just for counting the blank cells in the range:

```
=COUNTIF(B8:D8,"")
=SUM((IF((B8:D8)="",1,0)))
```

Hoping anyone can help with the **continuous** problem.

| Count Blank | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 |  | 2 | 3 |
| 2(should be 1) |  | 2 |  |
| 2(should be 0) | 1 |  |  |

Comment: Could you clarify your logic? You said *If any of the following cell has value then stop counting* but almost all rows have at least one non blank cell in any column so why is the output like that? Detail how is your expected output calculated, please

Answer (score 2):

I found this: https://exceljet.net/formulas/get-first-non-blank-value-in-a-list

You don't really want to count anything, you just need to find the first non blank cell. You can try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(FALSE;ISBLANK(B2:D2);0)-1;COLUMNS(B2:D2))
```

This is an array formula, so press **ctrl+shift+enter** when entering it into a cell.

Comment: You should probably make the static 3 dynamic as well, e.g. `=IFNA(MATCH(1,N(B2:D2<>""),0)-1,COLUMNS(B2:D2))`

Comment: @JosWoolley you're right, that would probably be safer. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new (as of 2020) reduce and lambda functions:

`=VALUE(REDUCE(0, B1:D1, LAMBDA(prev, curr, IF(ISTEXT(prev), prev, IF(curr = "", prev + 1, TEXT(prev,"0"))))))`